# "Ant in "AntPathRequestMatcher

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

There are some classes in Spring Boot whose name start with an "Ant".

Example: AntPathRequestMatcher.

My question is: what does "Ant" stand for in this name? I mean, I get the PathMatcher portion but why the "Ant"? I want to know the reason behind this naming.

```
.formLogin()

            .loginPage( "/login" ).defaultSuccessUrl( "/user/home" )
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher( "/logout" ) ).logoutSuccessUrl( "/login" );*
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess because syntax of these matchers is inspired by [Ant build tool](http://ant.apache.org/) syntax. Ant was first wide spread build tool for Java. It is predecessor for Maven or Gradle.